# Dynamic Price Structured Data depending on quantity - Woocommerce

Tags: php, json, woocommerce, structured-data

I am trying to develop a function to update the price marking of a product depending on the quantity.

The code:

```
    function update_structured_price($data) {
  global $product;

  // Get the quantity selected from the URL parameter /?quantity=3
  $quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']) ? intval($_GET['quantity']) : 1;

  // Update the structured price only when the quantity is 3
  if ($quantity === 3) {
    // Get the total product price from the HTML generated by the Tiered Pricing Table for WooCommerce plugin
    $price_html = $product->get_price_html();
    preg_match('/<span class="data-price-rules-formated-price">(.*?)<\/span>/', $price_html, $matches);
    $total_price = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : '';

    // Update the price in the product's JSON-LD
    if (isset($data['offers'])) {
      $data['offers']['price'] = $total_price;
    }
  }

  // Return the updated data
  return $data;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_structured_data_product', 'update_structured_price', 10, 2);
```

I have tried small changes like 'data' to 'marckup' but it doesn't work. Google only recognizes the price of the individual product

Any suggestions?

Comment: _"I have tried small changes like 'data' to 'marckup' but it doesn't work."_ - not sure what you mean by that. (The word that you likely meant here though would probably be spelled `markup`.)

Comment: _"Google only recognizes the price of the individual product"_ - not sure what that is actually supposed to mean either. You are aware that Google will not always display data that is "live", yes? So their bot might have visited your product page at a time that the available quantity was different from what it is right now.

Comment: Sorry, exactly 'markup' ;)

I understand what you are telling me.

The goal of this is to be able to advertise product packs on Google without duplicating content.

The individual product is built under a url with its name:

mysite.com/product-a

The product pack is built with the quantity parameter in the url

mysite.com/product-a/?quantity=3

When sending the pack information to Google, it recognizes the price of the individual product and what I'm looking for is for Google to read the total price of the 3 units

Comment: I would guess that even for `mysite.com/product-a/?quantity=3`, your system probably outputs a `<link rel="canonical">` that contains the URL _without_ the query string parameter - so Google will take the latter as the "real" URL it is supposed to index.

Comment: I appreciated that solution, but 4000 products with packs means twice the number of product pages

Comment: Once again, not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can share video url :S This is what I am trying to do and explain. Sorry for not including audio: https://files.fm/f/md8jvbkew

Comment: So the issue appears to be exactly what I suspected, if I am seeing the output of your schema.org validation there correctly - the actually _used_ URL does not include the `u=5` query string parameter. And that would likely be due to the `canonical` not containing it either. _"but 4000 products with packs means twice the number of product pages"_ - yes, and? If you _want_ 1 basic version and 1 pack to be indexed per each individual product - then this _needs_ two distinctive URLs per product as well.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of what you're saying, check it out on Google: site:https://www.naturitas.es/p/suplementos/vitaminas/vitamina-d/vitamina-d3/vitamina-d3-k2-60-capsulas-vegetales-solaray?u=5

Comment: The purpose of a `canonical` link is to tell clients such as search engine bots, "this is the _real_ URL for this piece of content - please index _that_ one, instead of the current one." Your page with the `?u=5` at the end of the URL has a canonical link _without_ that parameter. If you want Google to index our `producturl?u=5`, then the canonical link that URL returns, must _also_ be `producturl?u=5`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay

I understand what you are telling us. The goal of the markup is not to index the packs, it is to 'trick' Google so that it does not reject them in the Merchant Center because the price of the Feed does not match the one it reads on the web.

Comment: I don't think Google makes a distinction between those two purposes. You will have to provide the correct canonical URL, so that prices from web and feed match. Whether you can perhaps still disable indexing of those URLs, so that they won't show in search results, but are taking into account as product data, I don't know, you'd have to test it.